# Angular Universal: Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lazy-loading, angular-universal

I'm developing a github repo which is an angular example app, that you can check it [here](https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular7-example-app).
Now I'm trying to add Angular Universal and deploy it to firebase (thats the reason because of the functions folder). Everything works fine, the hole build process and deployment but I'm stock with this error when running SSR in localhost:

```
Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'.
at NgModuleResolver.resolve (/Users/iramos/WebstormProjects/angular7-example-app/functions/dist/server.js:60692:23)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/iramos/WebstormProjects/angular7-example-app/functions/dist/server.js:59334:43)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (/Users/iramos/WebstormProjects/angular7-example-app/functions/dist/server.js:66754:51)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (/Users/iramos/WebstormProjects/angular7-example-app/functions/dist/server.js:66735:36)
at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (/Users/iramos/WebstormProjects/angular7-example-app/functions/dist/server.js:66695:37)
at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (/Users/iramos/WebstormProjects/angular7-example-app/functions/dist/server.js:87477:31)
...
```

Steps to reproduce the error:

1. Clone the repo
2. npm i;
3. npm run build:ssr and then npm run start:ssr
4. Go to localhost:4000

I'm going to paste the most important parts here, but you can check the hole repo.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start:ssr": "node functions/dist/server",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "build:prod:es": "ng build --configuration=production-es",
    "build:server:prod": "ng run angularexampleapp:server:production",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "npm run build:prod && npm run build:prod:es && npm run build:server:prod",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server"
}
```

**webpack.server.config.js**

```
// Work around for https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
    server: './server.ts'
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {extensions: ['.ts', '.js']},
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'functions/dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader'}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

**server.ts**

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
// Express Engine
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import {provideModuleMap} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'functions/dist/browser');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./functions/dist/server/main');

// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {req});
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**angular.json**

```
...
"configurations": {
    "production-en": {
        "optimization": true,
        "outputHashing": "all",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "extractCss": true,
        "namedChunks": false,
        "aot": true,
        "extractLicenses": true,
        "vendorChunk": false,
        "buildOptimizer": true,
        "serviceWorker": true,
        "baseHref": "/",
        "budgets": [
           {
             "type": "initial",
             "maximumWarning": "2mb",
             "maximumError": "5mb"
           }
        ],
        "fileReplacements": [
           {
             "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
             "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
           }
        ]
    }
}

...

"server": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
    "options": {
       "outputPath": "functions/dist/server",
       "main": "src/main.server.ts",
       "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
    },
    "configurations": {
       "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
              "src/app/styles"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Things that I already tried:

1. Delete "outputHashing" from angular.json
2. Remove lazy loading routes (only one in heroes module)
3. Turn off optimization flag in angular json config

None of that worked.

I would appreciate any help! Please!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to remove one folder with some scripts that were included during the build process. You can find the final code in the github repository.

Comment: could you tell what folder and which scripts did you remove?

Comment: The problem was that because of firebase I was generating a dist folder which was included when running npm run build:ssr. If you need help, provide me a repo and I will check it...

Comment: actually it is in Gitlab now, what if I sent archived files?

Comment: ramossilvanismael@gmail.com or just send me the url to the repo!

Comment: @ismaestro I have exactly the same problem!

Comment: Can you be more specific? what folder? What should be done here in order to solve this issue